# Memoryview of numpy array can't handle assigning to the whole axis

Tags: python, numpy, cython, memoryview

I'm trying to convert my code to Cython. 
I'm trying to assign new values to an axis by passing an array of values.
Here is an example code:

```
cdef double[:,:] array_view = array
for t in range(tau):
    array_view[:,t] = np.sum(func(data_view), axis = 1)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I've checked what is returned by `np.sum(func(data_view), axis = 1)` and it is an array of correct length and shape. The `array` from which `array_view` is generated has also the right shape. 
Does anyone have any clue on what could causes the problem?
As I'm a beginner in Cython, there might be something obvious here that I'm missing.

EDIT:
Here is a minimal code example that produces the same error:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


cpdef error():
    arr = np.zeros((10,10), dtype = np.double)
    cdef double[:,:] arr_view = arr
    arr_view[:,0] = np.array([1 for i in range(10)], dtype = np.double)
    return arr
```

Comment: Which is the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Line #3 of my code snippet. Bascially when the assignin happens. I can do `np.sum(func(data_view), axis = 1)` with no error, and it produces the expected results, so the error really happens at the assigning step;

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve], right now we cannot run your code as it is to reproduce the error.

Comment: I've now added a minimal reproducible example, thank you for telling me this @ead

Comment: The meaning for cython's memory view is not the same as for numpy's arrays: for memory views it means "set all these values (on the left-hand side) to the same (double) value (on the right-hand side)". I cannot find this part in the documentation, but this is easy to see from the generated C-code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanaton! Then, is iterating through a memoryview version of an array faster than directly assigning the np.array on the whole axis at the same time?